# Insert comma in an array

Tags: python

I have got this result when I print my variable

```
print a.output2.data

[  4.72796516e+01   4.72796516e+01   8.85784539e-06 ...,  -8.85784721e-06
   0.00000000e+00   3.14159274e+00]
```

I would like to have an array with comma
something like this

```
[  4.72796516e+01 ,  4.72796516e+01 ,  8.85784539e-06 ,...,  -8.85784721e-06
   0.00000000e+00 ,  3.14159274e+00]
```

how can i do to add the comma in this array?

Comment: What is `type(a.output2.data)`? Is is a string? Are you talking about printing or actually wanting an list?

Answer (score 1):

`a.output2.data` is probably an `np.array`. Try `list(a.output2.data)`